# Limit the number of repetitive consecutive characters in a string

Tags: python, nlp, data-preprocessing

I'm preprocessing tweets and need to set the maximum limit of the number of consecutive occurrences of "@USER" to 3 times. For example, a tweet like this:

> this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER

after processing, should look like this:

> this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER

I was able to achieve the desired result with a `while` loop, however, I'm wondering if someone knows how to do it a simpler way. Thanks!

```
tweets = ["this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER"]

K = "@USER"
limit = 3
i = 0
for tweet in tweets: 
    tweet = tweet.split(' ')

    while i < len(tweet):
        if tweet[i].count(K) > limit:
            tweet[i] = K*int(limit)
            tweet = " ".join(str(item) for item in tweet)
        i +=1

print(tweet)
# Output: this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `re` to replace 4 or more occurrences of `@USER` with three:

```py
tweet = "this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER"
re.sub(r'(@USER){4,}', r'@USER@USER@USER', tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions.

```py
>>> import re

>>> re.sub(rf'({k}){{4,}}', k*3, tweets[0])
'this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER'
```

Converted to a more general function:

```py
def limit_substring_repeats(s, substr, max_repeats):
    import re
    return re.sub(rf'({substr}){{{max_repeats+1},}}', substr*max_repeats, s)


>>> limit_substring_repeats(tweets[0], k, 3)
'this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER'

>>> limit_substring_repeats(tweets[0], k, 2)
'this tweet contains hate speech @USER@USER about a target group @USER@USER'

>>> limit_substring_repeats(tweets[0], k, 1)
'this tweet contains hate speech @USER about a target group @USER'
```